# Type I error question

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, type-i-and-ii-errors

I have this question from a previous exam, since it didn't worth much points I suspect it should be something tricky.

> How to achieve a statistical test where the Type I error  risk is $0$?

Is it enough to say that we can make this statistical test to have the risk  $0$ by never rejecting the null hypothesis?

Otherwise can anyone explain it abit more rigurously?

Comment: By never rejecting the null hypothesis.

Comment: _What_ did you correct? There is no such thing as the false positive hypothesis, only the null hypothesis and the alternative hypothesis, or maybe just the null, and in either case, it is only the null hypothesis that can be rejected and it is emphatically the case that non rejection of the null is not equivalent to a whole-hearted embrace of the null hypothesis.

Comment: I am sorry, I need some sleep!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do it by only doing tests where you know the null is false. But that might be viewed as a "smart ass" answer on an exam (even though it's correct).

Comment: Haha, that is indeed smart.

Comment: What about the type II error, In order to achieve a risk of $0$ there is correct to do it when we know the null hypothesis is true?

Comment: The null is pretty much never exactly true.